# remove first line in bash

Tags: bash

Do you have a method to quickly remove the first line of a file in bash shell ? I mean using sed or stuff like that.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339483/how-can-i-remove-the-first-line-of-a-text-file-using-bash-sed-script

Answer (score 65, accepted):

One-liners in reverse order of length, portable unless noted.

`sed` (needs `GNU sed` for `-i`):

```
sed -i 1d file
```

[`ed`](https://superuser.com/questions/284258/remove-first-line-in-bash#comment296581_284270) (needs e.g. `bash` for `$'...'` expansion and here string):

```
ed file <<< $'1d\nw\nq'
```

`awk`:

```
awk NR\>1 infile > outfile
```

[`tail`](https://superuser.com/questions/284258/remove-first-line-in-bash#284261):

```
tail -n +2 infile > outfile
```

`read` + `cat`:

```
(read x; cat > outfile) < infile
```

`bash` built-ins:

```
while IFS= read -r; do ((i++)) && printf %s\\n "$REPLY" >> outfile; done < infile
```

Comment: or `ed file1 <<< $'1d\nw\nq'`

Comment: In my case, tail is 15 times slower than sed. tail needs 13.5s, sed needs 0.85s. My file has ~1M lines, ~100MB. MacBook Air 2013 with SSD.

Comment: I like the `awk` cmd the best.

Answer (score 19):

```
$ tail -n +2 <<< $'1\n2\n3'
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dd

```
fn="The-BIG-FILE.txt"
fll=$(( $(head -n 1 $fn | wc -c) + 1))
dd if="$fn" of="${fn}.out" bs=1M iflags=skip_bytes skip=$fll
echo "Files differ by $(( $(find $fn* -printf "%s - \n" ; echo "0") )) bytes. First line of $fn is $fll bytes."
```

*Add any `iflags=` and `oflags=` you might need - with commas separating them.*